# External DNS: Configure it in all namespaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, external-dns

I have successfully installed `external-dns` in my Kubernetes cluster following the official steps on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md), it creates a Route53 record and I am able to access it correctly. I installed this on a specific namespace.

My question is, do I need to deploy `external-dns` on each namespace (and then creating the service account, cluster role binding and deployment) or I can use the same deployment across namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, you don't need to deploy it more than once. If you don't specify a namespace in the args section of your external-dns deployment using `--namespace=`, it works for all of the namespaces in the cluster.
[image]